# ERROR in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

Without being sure how I caused this, the following error now occurs whenever I attempt to run a website by means of `npm run serve`:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Universidad\WebDevelopment\cocinillas\elcocinillas\frontend\elcocinillas\node_modules\vuex\dist\vuex.esm-bundler.js'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling different versions of `vuex`, with no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the file exist? If not, have you installed the modules?

Comment: Delete node_modules and reinstall the dependencies